# Tkinter auto-py-to-exe distorted widgets when running in laptop with no python installed. in

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, exe, auto-py-to-exe

I have made a python tkinter program and converted it to exe using auto-py-to-exe, it is not showing GUI properly on a laptop with no python installed.I have used (.place) to set proper alignment of widgets but it is showing distorted on a different laptop with no python installed.  What could be the solution for this??? Can anybody help.

Comment: Let me know if you want more information. I used auto-py-to-exe to convert this py file. Didn't try on anything else if any suggestion please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to stop using `place`. `pack` and `grid` make for much more responsive UIs. With `place` it's up to you to account for different resolutions, different window sizes, and different fonts.

Comment: I have set resizable(0,0) to all the window still (place) is not working as it should?? This is good suggestion but my code is very long and I have to redo every thing. If there is any way where I can use .place() and still make it work. Please

Comment: @PANKAJ: `place` is working as it's documented to work. If the display you're running on is of a different resolution, your the system has different default fonts, the use of `place` will likely result in windows that look different.

Comment: Ohh ok Place works on resolution. Right absolutely right. It makes sense to me now. I have to try with grid. Thank you for the help. Much appreciated. 

Comment: Can i use relx and rely to have it relative to the window. will that work??

Comment: @PANKAJ: it will work to a degree, but it won't be perfect. You'll end up with larger margins in some places, smaller in others, etc.